# global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break() error when trying to add a second input to a "public const string" in a public class

Tags: windows, serialization, constants, unhandled-exception

```
public class PlayerFile 
    {
        public const string CricketTeamFile = "CricketFile";
        public const string FootballTeamFile= "FootballFile";

        public static async Task<List<Player>> ViewMyPlayers(string type)
        {
            List<Player> Team;
            var Serializer = new  DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Player>));
            if (type == "Cricket")
            {
                var MyStream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(CricketTeamFile);
                Team = (List<Player>)Serializer.ReadObject(MyStream);
            }
            else
            {
                var MyStream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForReadAsync(FootballTeamFile);
                Team = (List<Player>)Serializer.ReadObject(MyStream);
            }
            return Team;
        }

        public static async Task AddToFile(List<Player> a, string type)
        {
            var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Player>));
            if (type == "Cricket")
            {
                using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(CricketTeamFile, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
                {
                    serializer.WriteObject(stream, a);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(FootballTeamFile, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
                {
                    serializer.WriteObject(stream, a);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

I am using a const string to store the values of different objects of a class into `CricketTeamFile` etc. (aim being able to retain the data even after the application is closed, this data should never be deleted unless app is uninstalled)

The `AddToFile` method works once, but when called upon the second time device throws `global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()` error and breaks. On emulator everything's working.